# Why does android studio show the same tip of the day always?

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I open android studio the same tip of the day gets popped up always so, is there any way to make different tips pop up every time, or is it because of the language which I selected to code in?

Comment: If you open it numerous times within a span of a day, of course it's going to show you the same tip of the day - it's supposed to refresh every 24 hours. If you're checking in every day and you are still getting the same tips try uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but still, I am getting the same tip of the day always @TomJoney